# Simple XPath predicate not working

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping

I'm running the following PHP snippet that evaluates an XPath query agains the source of a HTML page. The query seems correct and I tested it with some online XPath testers, but I won't get any match.

```
<?php
$details = new DOMDocument();
@$details->loadHTMLFile('http://www.astagiudiziaria.com/beni/lotto_unico_genova_via_della_pigna_6b_-_proc_n_583_14_trib_di_genova/index.html');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($details);
$procedimento = $xpath->query('.//ul[preceding-sibling::h2="Informazioni sulla procedura"]/li[(starts-with(., "R.G.E. N°") or starts-with(., "N°")) and not(starts-with(., "N° IVG"))]');
echo $procedimento->length; // returns 0, expected 1
?>
```

Seems that removing the part `and not(starts-with(., "N° IVG"))` solves the problem (but I need this clause).

What maybe the problem with that XPath query?

Answer (score 0):

I'd forget to check if the source contains spaces in the source. This works:

```
.//ul[preceding-sibling::h2="Informazioni sulla procedura"]/li[(starts-with(normalize-space(.), "R.G.E. N°") or starts-with(normalize-space(.), "N°")) and not(starts-with(normalize-space(.), "N° IVG: "))]
```

Comment: Congrats for finding the solution yourself. In case you did not know yet, you can also [accept your own answer after a grace period of 48 hours](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).